# How to reduce Untyped λ-Calculus to Normal Form?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have an assignment to do which involves reducing an Untyped λ-Calculus expression to Normal Form. I am struggling to come to terms with Lambda Calculus though.

For example, one small part of the expression is:

```
((λ n f x . n f (f x)) (λ f x . x))
```

Does this mean that we substitute `(λ f x . x)` in for every n, f and x? Giving us the following:

```
((λ n f x . (λ f x . x) (λ f x . x) ((λ f x . x) (λ f x . x))))
```

If so, can this be reduced further? I know I am probably way off with this, but I just do not understand it; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **EDIT: Thanks to @ljedrz Comment.**
>
> Before doing the reduction is worth noting that:
>   $$ (\lambda n f x . n ~ f (f ~ x)) = (\lambda n f x .((n f) (f ~ x))) $$
>   This is a convention, the parenthesis always associate to the left

It can be reduced further, but I advise you to change the second expression to an $\alpha$-equivalent one.

$$ \Big(\big(\lambda n f x . (n ~ f) (f ~ x) \big) ~ (\lambda h y . y) \Big) $$

This might not be necessary in this specific problem, but might also save you some headache later trying to keep track if some free variables got captured.

\begin{align*}
\Big(\big(\lambda \color{red}{n} f x . \color{red}{n} ~ f (f ~ x)\big) ~ \color{red}{(\lambda h y . y)} \Big) &\rightarrow_\beta \big[n ~ / ~(\lambda h y . y)\big] \big(\lambda f x . n ~ f (f ~ x)\big)\\
 &\rightarrow_{\alpha} \big( \lambda f x. (\lambda h y. y) ~ f ~ (f~x) \big)\\
\Big( \lambda f x. \big((\lambda \color{red}{h} y. y) ~ \color{red}{f}\big) ~ (f~x) \Big) &\rightarrow_{\beta} \Big(\lambda f x.\big[h ~ / ~ f \big]\big(\lambda y.y\big) ~ (f ~ x) \Big)\\
\Big( \lambda f x. ((\lambda y. y)) ~ (f~x) \Big) &\rightarrow_{\beta} \Big(\lambda f x.\big[y ~ / ~ (f ~ x)\big]y\Big)\\
 &\rightarrow_{\alpha} \Big(\lambda f x. (f ~ x) \Big)
\end{align*}

Which cannot be reduced further.

Comment: Thank you, I understand most of this, but just at the end when you substitute`[h/(f(fx))]` Does this just become nothing because there is no `h` on the right side of the dot?

Comment: Yes, in this case this is just a function that consumes it's argument and does nothing, since there's no bound $h$
to actually do the substitution.

Comment: @ljedrz Oh yes, these annoying parenthesis. That's what I get for doing directly on LaTeX. I'm going to fix it, thank you for spotting the mistake!

Comment: There's a typo, I think. The last $\to_\beta$ should lead to $\lambda f x . [y/fx] y$, without the $\lambda y$. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier (I do) to practice β-reductions using [De Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index), as they make α-conversions unnecessary and the indices help keep track of the substitution order.

Using them, the reduction (normal order) of your expression would look as follows ($\color{blue}{abstraction\ to\ drop}$, $\color{red}{bound\ variable\ to\ substitute}$, $\color{green}{the\ substitute\  expression}$):

\begin{align}
(\color{blue}{λ}λλ\color{red}{3}2(21))\color{green}{(λλ1)}\\
λλ(\color{blue}{λ}λ1)\color{red}{2}(21)\\
λλ(\color{blue}{λ}\color{red}{1})\color{green}{(21)}\\
λλ21
\end{align}